# Peripheral device found but can't connect to it

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my application i can scan for peripheral device just fine, but can't connect to it. Here is the code for connecting to the master device:

```
    bleGatt = masterDevice.connectGatt(currentContext,false,gattCallback);
    if(bleGatt == null){
        Log.w(TAG,"Unable to create GATT client");
    }
```

if i change the autoconnect flag to true, like:

```
bleGatt = masterDevice.connectGatt(currentContext,true,gattCallback);
```

then device does connects but, my custom service and characteristics are not discovered onServicesDiscovered call back. I think its some problem with this code running on device with API greater than 21

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Any luck on this? I can connect sometimes, but other times my central device discovers but cannot connect. Weird..